# Error in truffle initial migration file

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I'm learning solidity with the book "Master etherum". I'm trying to use following program in truffle.

https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/code/Solidity/Faucet4.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC-BY-SA-4.0

// Version of Solidity compiler this program was written for
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

// Our first contract is a faucet!
contract Faucet {
    address payable owner;

    // Contract constructor: set owner
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // Access control modifier
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    // Accept any incoming amount
    receive() external payable {}

    // Contract destructor
    function destroy() public onlyOwner {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }

    // Give out ether to anyone who asks
    function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {
        // Limit withdrawal amount
        require(withdraw_amount <= 0.1 ether);

        // Send the amount to the address that requested it
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
    }
}
```

Since now truffle init won't create migration file under migration folder, I've tried code like this for initial migration

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

But I keep getting error "Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum definition.", even it compiled successfully in truffle.

I've tried add "pragma solidity ^0.6.4" on top of the file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Neverminds guys, I found my 1_initial_migrations file was .sol and I change it into .js. Then it works!